# Htaccess 301 redirect by stripping part of string url to correct url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Pl advise, we made a mistake in creating lot of duplicate content for site in a section usedtoys
How to use htaccess to remove :- 'brand' & 'location' from url & redirect to correct url

For eg. **correct url**

```
   http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=category&Itemid=3
```

**Incorrect URL**

```
 http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=category&Itemid=3&brand=1
 http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=category&Itemid=3&brand=1&location=delhi
```

or
**Correct URL**

```
   http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=category&Itemid=3&limitstart=45
```

**Incorrect URL**

```
     http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=category&Itemid=3&brand=1&limitstart=45
     http://www.abc.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=category&Itemid=3&brand=1&location=delhi&limitstart=45
```

How to create a 301 redirect in htaccess so that any url having com_toys - with brand and/or location can be stripped and redirected to there correct url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_toys(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&brand=([^&]+)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?%1%3 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)option=com_toys(&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&location=([^&]+)(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?%1%3 [L,R=301]
```

in the htaccess file in your document root, preferably above any rules that you already have.

Comment: Hello Jon, Thanks - but how to make this restrict the rule only to one component i.e com_toys . The rule should only be applicable in com_toys. I have not tested this as have brand as string with other component but there the additional filters are not there and hence no duplicate url. How to restrict the rule to com_toys only. thanks

Comment: @Ruchika Add another condition to check for that query string (see edit)